# systemd - php worker

Tags: php, linux, systemd, backgroundworker

Подскажите пожалуйста, как через systemd линукса создать php-worker ?

нужно чтобы php скрипт постоянно слушал сервер очередей. если воркер упал - создается снова. Автозапуск при запуске ОС.

сейчас это я сделал через супервизор.
На продакшене админы по каким-то причинам не хотят ставить сторонее ПО, и говорят что это можно сделать через systemd.

Пробовал гуглить, но запутался в разных терминологиях.

Answer (score 1):

Коль админы такие продуманные, сами бы инит и написали бы. Тащемта это их задача (или devops'a, есть такой присутствует в конторе)

```
[Unit]
Description=PHPWorker

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php
PIDFile=/var/run/php/php-worker.pid
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
```

Залить этот код в `/etc/systemd/system/php-worker.service`. Дока по юнитам - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html